# picking up values from a spreadsheet while using arrayformulas, and store the template as PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the script I'm trying to get working. I'm a newbie here, and so maybe someone could help me a little bit. As soon as the form is summited, on Google sheet are calculated two values based on the data which were collected on formsubmit(using arrayformula for the entire column). The values from those cells where array formula is applied, are not saved on my pdf. Only the values which were entered over the form are available on pdf.
any ideas?
Thank you all!

```
 function afterFormSubmit(e) {
  const info = e.namedValues;
  const pdfFile =  createPDF(info);
  const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("students").getRange(entryRow, 9).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());
  

}

function createPDF(info){

const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("my pdf folder");
const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("my temp folder");
const templateDOC = DriveApp.getFileById("my template doc");
 
const newTempFile = templateDOC.makeCopy(tempFolder);

const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
const body = openDoc.getBody();
body.replaceText("{_}", info['Marcaj de timp'][0]);
body.replaceText("{__}", info['First name'][0]);
body.replaceText("{___}", info['Last name'][0]);
body.replaceText("{____}", info['Total score'][0]);
body.replaceText("{_____}", info['Results'][0]);

openDoc.saveAndClose();

const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['First name'][0] + " " + info['Last name'][0]);

return pdfFile;

}
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c36DVXMz6Ctgzkr4O-mA7Og9HagIK1kj5LAtldrxpaA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: And here is the template link   https://docs.google.com/document/d/1paeFvkAHIU3zwXXEXaxt4nvG7pMvJ5cViWi5ZcQaU10/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the samples. About `on google sheet are calculated two values based on the data witch were collected on formsubmit(using arrayformula for the entire colmun). The values from those cells where array formula is applied, are not saved on my pdf.`, in your situation, is it `Total score`? If my understanding is correct, where does the value of `Total score` come from?

Comment: the value from that column named TotalScore it is a sum of ScorNet and ScorBrut (those values are entered on form submit). here is the link for form submit : 
 https://forms.gle/cDN7NsWJt7JMZ1QD6

Comment: or.. I can give you the full acces for the folder i've been working on :  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wwK9-jAU96xdQEWCN2MZaTMJVONcCTte?usp=sharing